# R - lm p-Value loop

Tags: r, lm

I have a small problem with my R code. I think it is pretty easy to solve but I have just very little experience with R.

I have a linear Model and after using the drop1 functions I have p-values (see code below). I have done this for my first term A1.

So I want to do the same for A2 A3 and so on and would like to store all p-values in one file. I need to extract sie p-values and use some kind of loop. What kind of function do I need? How do I extract the p-values?

```
mod1<-lm(A1~B+C, data=ipo) 
drop1(mod1, test="F")


dput(head(ipo, 20))
structure(list(C = c(461.875, 441.85, 2133.025, 2213.704167, 
1533.120833, 1423.529167, 1011.6875, 985.1, 221.2708333, 200.1291667, 
336.875, 310.6875, 228.7583333, 220.4875, 452.7416667, 435.5416667, 
242.0041667, 232.4833333, 411.4458333, 412.5875), A1 = c(32925L, 
30797L, 162617L, 159828L, 110595L, 112922L, 78285L, 73708L, 14542L, 
14271L, 24484L, 23792L, 18269L, 15513L, 34383L, 32109L, 16531L, 
17279L, 30179L, 29919L), A2 = c(32925L, 30797L, 162617L, 159828L, 
110595L, 112922L, 78285L, 73708L, 14542L, 14271L, 24484L, 23792L, 
18269L, 15513L, 34383L, 32109L, 16531L, 17279L, 30179L, 29919L
), B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("C", 
"A1", "A2", "B"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(ipo)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(ipo, 20))`.

Comment: Oke, I added it to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(type, EP, -B, -C) %>% 
  nest(-type) %>%  
  mutate(lm=map(data, ~lm(EP ~ B + C,data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(drop=map(lm, ~drop1(.,test = "F") %>% broom::tidy(.))) %>% 
  unnest(drop, .drop = T) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(df))
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  type  term     df        sumsq          rss   AIC statistic  p.value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A1    B         2      836829.   124151602.  317.    0.0543 9.47e- 1
2 A1    C         1 18532654282. 18655969056.  419. 2405.     7.18e-19
3 A2    B         2      836829.   124151602.  317.    0.0543 9.47e- 1
4 A2    C         1 18532654282. 18655969056.  419. 2405.     7.18e-19
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Bit it seems I can't use tidyverse with my version of R.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses package `reshape2`, function `melt` to reshape the data from wide to long format. The rest is base R only.

```
long <- reshape2::melt(ipo, id.vars = c("B", "C"))

sp <- split(long, long$variable)
res <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  fit <- lm(value ~ B + C, data = DF)
  d <- drop1(fit)[-1, ]
  attr(d, "heading") <- NULL
  d
})

do.call(rbind, res)
#     Df  Sum of Sq        RSS    AIC
#A1.B  2 8.3683e+05 1.2415e+08 316.83
#A1.C  1 1.8533e+10 1.8656e+10 419.07
#A2.B  2 8.3683e+05 1.2415e+08 316.83
#A2.C  1 1.8533e+10 1.8656e+10 419.07
```

Comment: Thank zou for the code. Looks great. How do it get the p-values and put it in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution that just extracts the p-values. This should get you started--let me know if you are unable to change the output how you would like it. Good luck!!

```
# Get DV names
dvs <- names(ipo)[2:3]

# Create formula objects
formula_text <- paste0(dvs, " ~ B + C")
formulas <- lapply(formula_text, formula)

# Run models with drop1
models <- lapply(formulas, function(x){
  drop1(lm(x, data = ipo), test = "F")
})

# Extract p-values
model_pvals <- lapply(models, function(x) x[["Pr(>F)"]])

# Name and turn list into dataframe
names(model_pvals) <- formula_text

do.call(rbind, model_pvals)
           [,1]      [,2]         [,3]
A1 ~ B + C   NA 0.9473321 7.177227e-19
A2 ~ B + C   NA 0.9473321 7.177227e-19
```